# how to add a navigation drawer (sliding menu) inside only one of the tabs?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigation, android-sliding

I have 3 tabs in my app (A, B and C). I have created fragments for each of them. Now, I want a sliding menu / navigation drawer inside only tab A.The menu should show up only inside Tab A and not anywhere else. How can I do it ? Someone please help !

Comment: How about adding a navigation drawer in the regular way (see api guide) and just disable the gesture (locking the drawer) and disable actionbardrawertoggle when on specific tabs?

Comment: Can you point me to a tutorial ?

Comment: @Gyebro can't I do this any other way ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html - to lock the `NavigationDrawer` do like this in the specific `Fragments` where you want it closed: `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);` and in the `Fragment` where it should be unlocked: `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);` - this is merely what @Gyebro stated with a link and some code...